# How to transform excel VBA code into Javascript for Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

everyone. I need to change a code that I created in VBA to javascript and put it into Google Sheets. Does anyone know how I can do this? The code is below

```vb
Sub Influencers_automacao()
  Sheets(1).Activate
  Range("A1").Select
  Selection.End(xlDown).Select
  k = Selection.Row
  For t = 2 To Sheets.Count
    j = 2
    For i = 2 To k
      If Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(t).Name Then
        Sheets(t).Cells(j, 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)
        Sheets(t).Cells(j, 2) = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
        j = j + 1
      End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: what is `xlDown` ? this is incomplete code. Also, sometimes it's better create something from scratch rather than convert, so what does this code do exactly?

Comment: It's rather straightforward to "port" code from one language to another, provided you either know the target language, or are willing to learn the target language as you go along. On the latter, all you would need is a "command reference" for Javascript. Mozilla has a good one.

Comment: `Selection.End(xlDown).Select` seems to be correct code to me.  It should find the last non-empty cell in the selected range and select it.

Comment: what have you tried so far in gas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the answer is that you have to learn javascript and the google sheets object model, or at least enough of it to figure out how to do the same things in js that you're doing in VBA.

However, you can try using the macro converter, and your existing VBA is pretty simple so it might work without alterations, but you might have to tweak it. Let me know if this works, or if you encounter errors with the converted code and we can try to work through them.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/macro-converter/convert-files

Comment: Agree since its not a lot of code, should be straightforward to port (+1). But even if it were a lot of code, the porting will be painless if OP utilized a command reference from the source language to a command reference to the target language. The "google sheets object model" coming into play of course.

Comment: Yeah, I have real doubts that it will convert anything at all complex, but I just see a for loop and an if and a couple of selects and cell manipulations.  It just might work for him.  If not it will be easy enough to walk him through.  Those `SELECT`s aren't necessary at all, if it gets tripped up there.

Comment: OP seems dead on arrival in any event (no feedback), but it was a good discussion

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var output = []
  ss.getSheets().forEach(function (sh, i) {
    if (i > 0) output.push([
      sh.getName(), sh.getRange('A1').getValue(), sh.getRange('B1').getValue()
    ])
  })
  ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(2, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output)
}
```

change A1, B1 as necessary